# Specification of an Image field attached to forum topic node type?

Tags: 7, entities, media, nodes

I have somehow a strange issue with Fields : I've created an Image field for each of my content types. This image field allow the insertion of images into the node body with Insert and Colorbox. Everything work as wonder for all the content types... except for forum topics.

Indeed, when creating a new forum topic, my users can't see the Image field in the form. Also :

- Admin can see it, but not other users
- Users can perfectly see Image field when creating a new content of other type.

I've also checked : it's not a question of CSS or other modules hooking the field.

**Do you have any idea of what has to be done ?!  :/**

Answer (score 1):

have you created one image field that is shared between all of your content types, or a different image field for each content type? if it is the latter, this sounds like it is likely a permissions problem where one of the image fields is restricted to admin users only.

i'm not sure about D7, but there's a module in D6 called "content permissions" that seems like you should enable it but you really should avoid it if you can. There's probably an equivalent in D7 - the module denies access to all new fields for all user roles by default, and you have to explicitly give permissions back.

alternatively, it could be a caching issue. Drupal caching is much less aggressive for admins than for anonymous users so if you've made a few changes to your views that admins can see but anonymous can't, try clearing your site's cache.

Comment: The image field is shared by all content types, that's why I was a bit surprised ! I've also cleared the cache, but it's still not appearing...    :(

Comment: And actually I've combined core module content permissions w Access Content module ; but it can't be like a permission problem (I've checked people/permissions anyway) as it perfectly appears for other content types...

Comment: what if you make a new role just for testing that has all permissions and see if they can see the content? if they can, disable permissions one (or a few) at a time until you nail the culprit. if they can't, even after a few cache clears, then you can be pretty sure it isn't a permissions problem.